# Is there a way to rename a surname in an Ancestry tree?

Tags: surnames, ancestry.com, family-tree-maker

I imported a GEDCOM and the accents in the GEDCOM got misinterpreted for some surnames.  I'd like to fix this by doing a global replace of one surname with another, to replace the improper `Kovaïč` with the correct `Kovačič`.  I could do it one at a time on Ancestry.com but there are around 300, so that is very slow.  Instead, I'd like to edit en mass.

I tried editing the 2017 format `.ftm` file on my Mac that syncs with ancestry.com, but it is not text format, so the surname does not appear as plain text in it.  If I export to GEDCOM and edit the GEDCOM, can I import it back into the same tree and not end up with two copies of people (incorrect and correct spelling)?  If I export to GEDCOM and make a new tree, would I risk losing any information?

Comment: I think your approach is basically a good one. A find & replace in a GEDCOM file would be quick, because it's textual. As for whether there's data loss... I don't believe so, but the best way is to try it yourself. Keep two trees on Ancestry.com for the time being, then play around, and see if any info is lost. I would pay close attention to the "sources" and "facts" info on persons, to see if they're preserved properly.